# $p^n\mid ((p^{n-m}+1)^j-1)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Let $m$ and $n$ be natural numbers, where $n>m\geq 1$ and $p$ be an odd prime.
Could we determine all natural numbers $j$ such that $p^n\mid ((p^{n-m}+1)^j-1)$?

Comment: Are you asking if this is true for all natural numbers $n,m,j$ and every prime $p\not=2$?

Comment: @Lovsovs I think what he wants is to find all $j$ in function of $m$ and $n$ so that its frue for every $p>2$

Comment: Dear Lovsovs, $m$, $n$ and $p$ are fixed and I want to find such $j$'s with this property.

Comment: I am sorry! There is a mistake in my question. I edited it.

Comment: Would the LTE Lemma help somehow?

Comment: Excuse me! What is the LTE Lemma?

Comment: @sebastian I would suggest you to read this article:
https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwji0_WI5JTPAhWIIsAKHYSMC9EQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fservices.artofproblemsolving.com%2Fdownload.php%3Fid%3DYXR0YWNobWVudHMvNC81LzYyZTQ0NjJlOGZhYzkwMmQwNzAxOTgyOTViMjY1Y2I2NGRhNjcx%26rn%3DTGlmdGluZyBUaGUgRXhwb25lbnQgTGVtbWEgLSBBbWlyIEhvc3NlaW4gUGFydmFyZGkgLSBWZXJzaW9uIDMucGRm&usg=AFQjCNGhUS19IaLGtIp6AL_eb0T7IBl7Sg&sig2=Z5n-Afzdls1TCM_eRhDNMg

Comment: @HeatTheIce, thank you! I'll see it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is enough.

Using the [LTE Lemma](https://services.artofproblemsolving.com/download.php?id=YXR0YWNobWVudHMvNC81LzYyZTQ0NjJlOGZhYzkwMmQwNzAxOTgyOTViMjY1Y2I2NGRhNjcx&rn=TGlmdGluZyBUaGUgRXhwb25lbnQgTGVtbWEgLSBBbWlyIEhvc3NlaW4gUGFydmFyZGkgLSBWZXJzaW9uIDMucGRm) lets define $\alpha:=v_p((p^{n-m}+1)^j-1)\Leftrightarrow p^\alpha\|(p^{n-m}+1)^j-1$. So $p^\alpha$ exactly divides $(p^{n-m}+1)^j-1$. Using now the Lemma we get $\alpha=v_p((p^{n-m}+1)-1)+v_p(j)=v_p(p^{n-m})+v_p(j)=n-m+v_p(j)$. It is enough that $\alpha\ge n$, bcs then we know that $p^n$ will divide $(p^{n-m}+1)^j-1$. So $v_p(j)\ge m$, which means $j$ is independent of $n$. Now we just have that $j=p^m\cdot t, t\in\mathbb{N}$ (this follows from the fact that $j=p^b\cdot k, k,b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k\ge m$ and $p\nmid k$ $\Rightarrow$$b=m+h,t=p^h\cdot k$).

Answer (score 0):

Use the binomial theorem on $(p^{n-m}+1)^j$. You'll see that the 1's will cancel and then you can look at the exponent to determine which $j$'s satisfy division.

Comment: @ Bo Rel, of course I did it but I could not determine such $j$'s